# Is it necessary to read data before close http response?

Tags: java, http-request

Is it necessary to read request data before calling the close method of response inside a http server in java?

I have a http server written by sun's http server. When I receive a http request, I just simply do the following steps:

- write my text to response body
- close the response

Does it matter to read the request body before closing the response?

Note that I have too many http requests on my server. (10000 call/sec.)

Comment: No you obviously don't have to read the body, but it defeats the point of http

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My benchmark says if request body does not have too much data, there is no big difference between two methods. I didn't get any timeout and other type of exceptions using both methods.

This is the time benchmark result for 1M request using 100 concurrent threads (10000 request per thread) on both methods:

- *Don't read request body*: `210,581ms`
- *Read request body*: `206,599ms`